# sql order by clause with multiple conditions

Tags: sql

can any body expalin me how to sort data in table using multiple conditions using order by clause

Ex : (Query) Display empno,ename,deptno,sal sort the output first base on name and

within name by deptno and with in deptno by sal.
  what is the process going on in this query
i mean i want to know, how to use multiple conditions in order by clause

Answer (score 2):

The data is sorted by the first column in the `order by` clause.

If two values have the same order then the second column in the `order by` clause is used for ordering and so on.

```
select * from your_table
order by name, 
         deptno,
         sal
```